# Run script only if file does not exist

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

In my VBScript I am trying to run another VBScript to create a desktop shortcut *if* that desktop shortcut doesn't exist. If the desktop link does exist, it should not do anything. However, currently even if the desktop shortcut exists, the VBScript still runs. Why? No syntax error.

```
Dim objFSO, strDirectory, strFile

Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

'getting script location
strPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)

'define directory & file
strDirectory = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
strFile = strDirectory & "\Desktop\My Program.lnk"

If objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
    'DO NOTHING
Else
    strDesk = "desktoplink.vbs"
    oShell.Run strDesk, 0, False
End If

'enclosing path to support spaces
HMIpath = strFolder & "\CHK.bat"
HMIpath = """" & HMIpath & """"

Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c " & HMIpath
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, False
```

Comment: AFAICS the code should do what you expect. Please double-check that `strFile` is what you expect it to be (`WScript.Echo strFile`) and that the file actually does exist (`dir "C:\path\echoed\by\vbscript"` in CMD).

Comment: I'd probably do `If Not objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then oShell.Run "desktoplink.vbs", 0, False`, though.

Comment: Interesting thing. Even with  "If Not objFSO.FileExists(strFile)" I was still running desktoplink.vbs. I then switched  My Program.lnk with notepad.lnk on my desktop an notepad.exe DID NOT OPEN. Looked at  My Program.lnk, and the link is going to a .vbs (open in windows base host). So if a .lnk  goes to a ..vbs file then If Not objFSO.FileExists(strFile) does not work? However works with a lnk file for .exe . I don't understand.

Comment: What is the file on your desktop? `My Program.lnk` or `My Program.vbs`? Please follow the advice from my first comment. My second comment was just a suggestion for simplifying the code a little (since I find having a conditional with an empty Else branch quite useless).

Comment: ... empty *Then* branch, of course.